# $request->input Returning Null in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-8

I want to try if i select a value that is in the "dropdown" it will automatically replace another value in the same page without updating the page, and using ajax, but on the controller part i get the message "request=null" i don't understand even though I have entered the name of the input from "view" to the controller.
this is some of my project code

> view.blade

```
<label class="col-sm-2 form-inline">Karyawan</label>
<select class="form-select select-name" id="idSelect" aria-label="Default select example" name="pilih-nama">
  <option value="">-Pilih Karyawan-</option>
   @foreach ($karyawan as $data)
      <option value=" {{$data->nip_kyn}}">{{$data->nama_kyn}}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

> Controller

```
public function showData(Request $request)
{
    $nip = $request->input('pilih-nama');
    $data = Karyawan::where('nip_kyn', $nip)->first();
    return response()->json(['data' => $data]);
}
```

> Ajax code in main view

```
    <script>
    $(document).on('change', '.select-name', function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        var hasil = $(this).val();
        // 
        if (hasil == '') {
            document.location.href = "unduhQR";
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{route('showData.index')}}",
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                data: hasil
            },
            success: function(res) {
                console.log(res.data)
                // $('.nama-kar').html(res.data.nama_kyn)
                // $('.idQr').html('NIP : ' + res.data.nip_kyn)
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                // console.log(xhr)
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

> my route

```
Route::post('/showQR', [QRCodeController::class, 'showData'])->name('showData.index');
```

but if i change in my controller like this

```
    $nip = 'NIP001'; // <-- Value from database
    $data = Karyawan::where('nip_kyn', $nip)->first();
    return response()->json(['data' => $data]);
```

its going work, but that's not dynamic,
any suggestion to solve this guys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the data like this

```
data: {pilih-nama: hasil}
```

and to be honest your variable names are not good. You should change them with good ones.